# Inquiry on a proof about the existence of a real number $x$ such that $x^{3} = 5$

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading a thread on MSE here: [Prove that there is a positive number x such that $ x^3= 5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1471326/prove-that-there-is-a-positive-number-x-such-that-x3-5)

I am reading the proof made by the original poster.

But, I don't understand one thing. In the first inequality, it is written that

$$b^{3} - 3b^{2}\epsilon - 3\epsilon = 5.$$

But if you solve the equation $\epsilon = (b^{3} - 5)/(3b^2 - 3)$ for $5$, we see that it is actually

$$b^{3} - 3b^{2}\epsilon + 3\epsilon = 5.$$

So, is the proof still valid? If not, how can I fix that part? I tried, but I cannot get it.

Comment: What about intermediate value theorem together with continuity of $x^3$?

Comment: @Michael Such problems are sometimes discussed in analysis classes long before notion of continuity is, so I presume we want to avoid using any such theorems.

Comment: I'm trying to prove it using by showing that it is the supremum of a set, as in the first post.

Comment: @stackofhay42 You spot an inequality mistake so you can just redefine $\epsilon = (b^3-5)/(3(b^2+1))$ which is again a positive number under the assumption $b^3>5$, and I think that suits your purposes.  However, this is a minor detail, the main idea is that if $b^3>5$, you want to show there is an $\epsilon>0$ such that $(b-\epsilon)^3>5$.  You can do that any way you like. (This is essentially a “continuity” argument in disguise).

Comment: What about that : $x^3$ is invertible on $\mathbb R$ because it is strictly increasing on $\mathbb R$. Hence $x^3$ is surjective, so $x^3=5$ must have a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a typo in the original post. If you define $\varepsilon=\frac{b^3-5}{3b^2+3}$, equivalently $5=b^3-3b^2\varepsilon-3\varepsilon$, then clearly $b-\varepsilon<b$ and we have $$(b-\varepsilon)^3>b^3-3b^2\varepsilon-3\varepsilon=5.$$

It boils down to this: the proof you read is fine, there is simply a minor typo in the proof that has now been corrected.